# Split RxJS observable output

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I'm building an observable from an event, which outputs text lines that confirm records which are divided by two empty lines. For example:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx


xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I'd like the observable to split the output by two new lines, so the subscriber gets the data in chunks.

How can I accomplish this using RxJS? It doesn't seem to have a function to perform this job.

I could subscribe to the observer, accumulate values and re-emit myself, but I believe there is a more elegant solution that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Best is to expose your requirements in a marble, which is basically your inputs and expected outputs on a timeline. Otherwise do you mean that your observable is only output one line at a time? Hence an empty line is just a \n?

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `buffer` and `sample` and `scan` could also work. Basically you accumulate inputs (i.e. lines) in a buffer. You release this buffer every time an observable emits a value, with `sample`. Then you make it so that observable emits a value every time it detects two consecutives `\n`. This can be achieved with `scan`. Note that this requires your `source$` to be a hot observable.

So, you could complete the following code and keep us updated if it worked in the end :

```
var detect_two_lines = function (acc, new_line)){
  // if new_line and last line of acc are both \n
  // then acc.arr_lines = [], acc.found = true
  // else acc.arr_lines.push(new_line), acc.found = false
}
var identity = function(x){return x}
var sample$ = source$.scan(detect_two_lines, {arr_lines:[], found:false})
                     .pluck('found')
                     .filter(identity);
var results$ = source$.buffer(sample$);
```